# Emulator doesn't show anything

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to start Android emulator, it is starting but nothing shown except white screen not even the android shining logo.

I have installed Android latest tools required. But still no luck.

I have also tried with Genymotion, same thing repeats here.

Comment: Which image version are you using? What kind of settings are you using for the emulator?

Comment: Post your manifest. Is there any errors in the logcat? Also, do you have a real device you can test on?

Comment: Check that you have enough RAM on your dev PC, I recall I saw posts where people complaining about such issues in this regard

Comment: Genymotion did same??. I m strange.

Comment: MY PC RAM is 3GB, 32bit Windows 7.

Comment: I tried to configure Genymotion according to [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjHk1VtLk8c). Everything working fine but at the last step of running emulator, it is showing just a blank white screen.

Comment: Have you installed Oracle Virtual tool box too???

Comment: Yes even configured it as per [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iIMmfemw8E)

Comment: @Angels When you launch emulator does it show all devices? Which screen size device are you launching?

Comment: @Piyush Gupta, Yes it is showing all the devices. I launched Nexus 4(4.7", 768 x 1280:xhdpi), but here in Memory Option: the RAM:1907, VM HEap: 64

Comment: @Angels First try to launch normal screen device 480x800

Comment: @Piyush Gupta,tried with 480x800 but the result is same white screen witout android logo

Comment: @Angels Can you share that screenshot ????

Comment: Yes I tried to post the screenshot yesterday with my questions, but stack threw a message that I need 10 reputations

Comment: @Angels Yeah you have to do that. Do one thing share screenshot to my Id from SO profile. I check it and let you know

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/users/1844392/piyush-gupta

Comment: @Angels Checked?????

Comment: @Piyush Gupta, I mailed the images, please check and reply back.

Comment: @Angels Oh still you have facing problem?  when did you mail me?

Comment: Yes the same problem, I have again installed ADT, and configured Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check are you following all steps to create AVD, Check SDK that you are using is downloaded properly or not. If not then download require SDK version, then recreate  AVD.

Comment: Yes I have downloaded everything completely. Deleted twice and reinstalled.